# OpenGL ES3: no matching overloaded function found for packUnorm2x16

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, glsles

I am trying to pack 2 float values into 1 uint value using `packUnorm2x16` method of OpenGL ES3 GLSL. But the compilation of the shader fails with `'packUnorm2x16': no matching overloaded function found` error.

This is my fragment shader:

```
varying highp vec2 vDisplacement;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(packUnorm2x16(vDisplacement), vec3(0.0));
}
```

I am trying to render a result to a GL_R32UI texture.

Comment: [`packUnorm2x16`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/packUnorm.xhtml) is supported since OpenGL ES 3.0. You've to add the version qualifier `#version 300 es` to the first lien of the fragment shader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`packUnorm2x16`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/packUnorm.xhtml) is supported since OpenGL ES 3.0. You've to add the version qualifier `#version 300 es` to the first lien of the fragment shader:

```c
#version 300 es

varying highp vec2 vDisplacement;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(packUnorm2x16(vDisplacement), vec3(0.0));
}
```